# Is there a way to read or see the files or information stored in RAM in a computer?

Tags: java, security, memory, ram, bytearrayinputstream

I'm working on a security project and I'm wondering how hard is it to read into the RAM memory of a computer.

For example, I have a Java program that reads an image into ByteArrayInputStream, how hard would it be for someone to see this file if I immediately deleted the original file stored in disk? The point of this is to make the file as secure as possible for the time of program being open. It doesn't matter if the file is lost forever after the program is interrupted.

Perhaps there's tools to look at these things? Would it be different if I made my program in .NET? perhaps easier or harder to do?

It was just a curious idea I got in my head. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Malicious processes can easily read other process' memory, and there is very little that you can do about that, especially in Java.  Look at C#'s `SecureString` class, and beware of the pagefile.

Comment: There must be a way to view the RAM. AFAIK, this is the basis of Cheat Engine's functionality; I don't know how else it would work. I've actually been meaning to try this. What would happen if in a low level language to tried to access memory you don't own, and catch the resulting exceptions? There might even be a compiler flag to allow this.

Comment: Yes, the folks at security have answered it http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/10643/recover-the-prior-contents-of-ram-from-a-turned-off-pc

Comment: I think it won't get any more basic than this @JoseLeon that's just amazing to me; I honestly thought RAM was a bit harder to look into because of its volatile nature.

Comment: You should probably first clearly define your threat model: who are your adversaries, where are they and what can they do? If the administrator of the computer is a potential adversary, the answer to your question is completely different than if your adversaries can only sniff at the memory bus on the motherboard or readout the content of the memory chips.

Comment: @Maflores16: No; that just means it's harder (though not impossible) to look at _after you turn of the computer_ (when it has no power).  Though that won't help the pagefile either.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet worst case scenario: the adversary takes full control of the computer remotely and install any type of tools to it. The only thing he can't do is look into the pre-compiled code or know beforehand which file was stored through the program. He can't also physically interact with the computer (ex: remove components, cool down ram, etc.).
 What would be different?

Comment: _ What would be different?_: your threat model is extremely pessimistic. Your adversary being able to take _full control of the computer_ leaves very few room for security, alas. If you have full control of a computer you can do whatever you want with user land processes (sniff, tamper...) And you do not even need any advanced tools.